# jquery create a tooltip that does not disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am looking to build a tooltip that allows the user to click links within that tooltip to allow them to navigate to various sections of the site. My problem is that the tooltip disappears when I leave the `a` with my mouse? what I want is for the tool tip to disappear if I change to a new `a` or click close on the tooltip, my jquery is as below currently,

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

    /*
     * Rollover jobwall logo and show job tooltip
     */
     $('ul#jobs li a').mouseenter(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass('active');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
                data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
                success:function(html) {
                    //alert($this);
                    $this.tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
                }
            });
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass
            $('#tooltip').remove();
        });


});
```

How can I make it so that the tooltip appears on mouse enter of an `a` button only disappear when the user closes it through clicking a close button, or moving to a new `a` allowing the user to actually enter the tooltip without it disappearing.

Comment: You want the tooltip to remain focused unless the user leaves focus on the anchor or the tooltip itself.  Do not give me a tooltip that stays overtop the page and makes me perform an action to go away.  If I hover over something accidentally while scrolling I will be pissed when it stays on the page.

Comment: Fair comment, but how would I keep it focused until I change the a i hovered over?

Comment: Maybe finding a tooltip extension would be easier than to code this. (ie: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)

Comment: @Detect I have used your solution but having a little trouble, the tooltip is not showing, is this because I populating the tooltip via ajax? Please see my edited javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `$('#tooltip').remove();` to the top of the mouseenter function should do the trick. This will not remove the tooltip when the mouse leaves and will remove it if it exists when a new `a` is entered.
This assumes that 1) you already have a close function and 2) `$('.active').append(html);` creates `#tooltip`.

As commented by Chris though, this may be frustrating for users.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) instead of [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

On the mouse leave event, you need to check to see if the mouse is located in the tooltip. If not, you can close it.